# PHP Socket Server Memory Leak

Tags: php, sockets, client-server, php-5.2

I have checked the memory whilst sending and receiving data over one connection, and I appear to be correctly clearing variables, as the memory returns to its previous value.

But for some reason if I make a new connection, then close the connection, memory is leaked. I believe the problem may be occurring when a socket is accepted.

I am using PHP 5.2.10

Hopefully one of you can find the time to have a play with the source and figure out where its gone wrong. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
    Class SuperSocket
        {
            var $listen = array();
            var $status_listening = FALSE;
            var $sockets = array();
            var $event_callbacks = array();
            var $recvq = 1;
            var $parent;
            var $delay = 100; // 10,000th  of a second
            var $data_buffer = array();

            function SuperSocket($listen = array('127.0.0.1:123'))
                {
                    $listen = array_unique($listen);
                    foreach ($listen as $address)
                        {
                            list($address, $port) = explode(":", $address, 2);
                            $this->listen[] = array("ADDR" => trim($address), "PORT" => trim($port));
                        };
                }

            function start()
                {
                    if ($this->status_listening)
                        {
                            return FALSE;
                        };
                    $this->sockets = array();
                    $cursocket = 0;
                    foreach ($this->listen as $listen)
                        {
                            if ($listen['ADDR'] == "*")
                                {
                                    $this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket'] = socket_create_listen($listen['PORT']);
                                    $listen['ADDR'] = FALSE;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    $this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket'] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
                                };
                            if ($this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket'] < 0)
                                {
                                    return FALSE;
                                };
                            if (@socket_bind($this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket'], $listen['ADDR'], $listen['PORT']) < 0)
                                {
                                    return FALSE;
                                };
                            if (socket_listen($this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket']) < 0)
                                {
                                    return FALSE;
                                };
                            if (!socket_set_option($this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket'], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1))
                                {
                                    return FALSE;
                                };
                            if (!socket_set_nonblock($this->sockets[$cursocket]['socket']))
                                {
                                    return FALSE;
                                };
                            $this->sockets[$cursocket]['info'] = array("ADDR" => $listen['ADDR'], "PORT" => $listen['PORT']);
                            $this->sockets[$cursocket]['channels'] = array();
                            $this->sockets[$cursocket]['id'] = $cursocket;
                            $cursocket++;
                        };
                    $this->status_listening = TRUE;
                }

            function new_socket_loop(&$socket)
                {
                    $socket =& $this->sockets[$socket['id']];
                    if ($newchannel =  @stream_socket_accept($socket['socket'], 0));//@socket_accept($socket['socket']))
                        {
                            socket_set_nonblock($newchannel);
                            $socket['channels'][]['socket'] = $newchannel;
                            $channel = array_pop(array_keys($socket['channels']));
                            $this->remote_address($newchannel, $remote_addr, $remote_port);
                            $socket['channels'][$channel]['info'] = array('ADDR' => $remote_addr, 'PORT' => $remote_port);
                            $event = $this->event("NEW_SOCKET_CHANNEL");
                            if ($event)
                            $event($socket['id'], $channel, $this);
                        };
                }

    function endswith($string, $test) {
        $strlen = strlen($string);
        $testlen = strlen($test);
        if ($testlen > $strlen) return false;
        return substr_compare($string, $test, -$testlen) === 0;
    }

            function recv_socket_loop(&$socket)
                {
                    $socket =& $this->sockets[$socket['id']];
                    foreach ($socket['channels'] as $channel_id => $channel)
                        {
                            unset($buffer);#Flush buffer
                            $status = @socket_recv($channel['socket'], $buffer, $this->recvq, 0);
                            if ($status === 0 && $buffer === NULL)
                                {
                                    $this->close($socket['id'], $channel_id);
                                }
                            elseif (!($status === FALSE && $buffer === NULL))
                                {
                                    $sockid = $socket['id'];
                                    if(!isset($this->data_buffer[$sockid]))
                                        $this->data_buffer[$sockid]='';

                                    if($buffer!="\r"&&$buffer!="\n")
                                    {
                                        //Putty ends with \r\n
                                        $this->data_buffer[$sockid].=$buffer;
                                    }
                                    else if($buffer!="\n") //ignore the additional newline char \n
                                    {
                                        $event = $this->event("DATA_SOCKET_CHANNEL");
                                        if ($event)
                                            $event($socket['id'], $channel_id, $this->data_buffer[$sockid], $this);
                                        unset($this->data_buffer[$sockid]);
                                    }

                                };
                        }
                }

            function stop()
                {
                    $this->closeall();
                    $this->status_listening = FALSE;
                    foreach ($this->sockets as $socket_id => $socket)
                        {
                            socket_shutdown($socket['socket']);
                            socket_close($socket['socket']);
                        };
                    $event = $this->event("SERVER_STOP");
                    if ($event)
                    $event($this);
                }

            function closeall($socket_id = NULL)
                {
                    if ($socket_id === NULL)
                        {
                            foreach ($this->sockets as $socket_id => $socket)
                                {
                                    foreach ($socket['channels'] as $channel_id => $channel)
                                        {
                                            $this->close($socket_id, $channel_id);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            foreach ($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'] as $channel_id => $channel)
                                {
                                    $this->close($socket_id, $channel_id);
                                };
                        };
                }

            function close($socket_id, $channel_id)
                {
                    unset($this->data_buffer[$socket_id]); //clear the sockets data buffer
                    $arrOpt = array('l_onoff' => 1, 'l_linger' => 1);
                    @socket_shutdown($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['socket']);
                    @socket_close($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['socket']);
                    $event = $this->event("LOST_SOCKET_CHANNEL");
                    if ($event)
                    $event($socket_id, $channel_id, $this);
                }

            function loop()
                {
                    while ($this->status_listening)
                        {
                            usleep($this->delay);
                            foreach ($this->sockets as $socket)
                                {
                                    $this->new_socket_loop($socket);
                                    $this->recv_socket_loop($socket);
                                };
                            $event = $this->event("END_SOCKET_CHANNEL");
                            if ($event)
                            $event($this);
                        };
                }

            function write($socket_id, $channel_id, $buffer)
                {   
                    @socket_write($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['socket'], $buffer);
                    @socket_write($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['socket'], 'Server memory usage: '.memory_get_usage().'/'.memory_get_peak_usage(true)."\r\n");
                }

            function get_channel_info($socket_id, $channel_id)
                {
                    return $this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['info'];
                }

            function get_socket_info($socket_id)
                {
                    $socket_info = $this->sockets[$socket_id]['info'];
                    if (empty($socket_info['ADDR']))
                        {
                            $socket_info['ADDR'] = "*";
                        };
                    return $socket_info;
                }

            function get_raw_channel_socket($socket_id, $channel_id)
                {
                    return $this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]['socket'];
                }

            function remote_address($channel_socket, &$ipaddress, &$port)
                {
                    socket_getpeername($channel_socket, $ipaddress, $port);
                }

            function event($name)
                {
                    if (isset($this->event_callbacks[$name]))
                    return $this->event_callbacks[$name];
                }

            function assign_callback($name, $function_name)
                {
                    $this->event_callbacks[$name] = $function_name;
                }
        };

    ?>
```

Server.php

```
include("supersocket.class.php");

function startswith($string, $test) {
    return strpos($string, $test, 0) === 0;
}

function newdata($socket_id, $channel_id, $buffer, &$server)
    {
        //$server->write($socket_id, $channel_id, ">".$buffer."\r\n");
        if($buffer=="STOP")
        {
            $server->stop();
        }
        else if($buffer=="DATETIME")
        {
            $server->write($socket_id, $channel_id, ">".date("dmYHis")."\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            $server->write($socket_id, $channel_id, ">BAD\r\n");
        }

    };

function newclient($socket_id, $channel_id, &$server)
{
    $server->write($socket_id, $channel_id, "HEADER\n\r");
}

$socket = new SuperSocket(array('127.0.0.1:12345')); 
$socket->assign_callback("DATA_SOCKET_CHANNEL", "newdata");
$socket->assign_callback("NEW_SOCKET_CHANNEL", "newclient");
$socket->start();
//set_time_limit(60*2);
set_time_limit(60*60*24*5); //5 days
$socket->loop();
```

Edit: sorry you might need to change the socket accept back to:
if ($newchannel =  @socket_accept($socket['socket']))

Comment: if you constantly accept/close connections, is large amounts of memory leaked? some garbage collectors aren't as aggressive as others.

Comment: What about line 255? - I'm sorry but that doesn't really help me

Comment: I can leave this script running for a day, and the memory usage does not increase. It is only once I accept a real connection from my telnet client does the memory go up by around 500 bytes, then when I disconnect that client that 500 bytes stays. << This is my problem.

Comment: Does it stay forever? And more importantly the next connection does it also produce the same 500 bytes. I.e. does it leak memory until it dies or does it stop somewhere? PHP has a funny way of handling strings that means that it has a sweetspot somewhere. I once tried fixing memoryleaks but it didnt go away, when i accidentally left it running for a while the memory consumption stabilized and that's when I learned that it wasnt leaking, it was "caching". Just saying, doesn't have to be the case.

Comment: It does stay forever, it never stabilizes. The next connection and any after all add 500 bytes. There must be something I am not disposing of :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Channel array was never removed upon closing the connection, surprised no one picked up on this. Memory usage is now super tight.

unset($this->sockets[$socket_id]['channels'][$channel_id]);

But it does mean that any event for LOST_SOCKET_CHANNEL is pretty useless for the time being.

Will accept my own answer when stack over flow allows. Thanks for all your help ppl .. i guess..

Comment: Nobody caught it probably because you included several hundred lines of code; for a help site, very few, if any, are going to actually read and debug that much custom-written code. That is why you should also post the shortest test-case possible that demonstrates the problem. Likewise, if you had reported this to bugs.php.net with that much code, they likely would have closed the issue and suggested that you reduce your test case. Here, you basically just threw all your code at SO in the hopes that we'd debug your entire script for you -- sorry, but I don't think that's why anyone comes here.

Answer (score 1):

> then close the connection, memory is leaked

This is a tricky one - even the standard reference counting garbage collector only kicks in at intervals which are difficult to predict. Calling [gc_collect_cycles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)() should trigger the gc though. Try calling that whenever you close a connection and see if it makes a difference.

If you're still seeing problems - then check if you've got the cyclic reference counter compiled in - if not, then get it.

Comment: `gc_collect_cycles` is part of PHP 5.3's new and improved GC system.  The OP is using PHP 5.2.x, which is certainly part of the problem.